# Return array of objects from query

Tags: php

I currently have the following my_sql logic:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results('
                        SELECT
                            catname as subcatname,categoryid, 
                            (SELECT 
                                catname 
                            FROM 
                                isc_categories 
                            WHERE 
                                categoryid= '.(int)$id.') as catname
                        FROM
                            isc_categories
                        WHERE
                            catparentid = '.(int)$id.'
                        AND  
                            catvisible=1
                        ORDER BY
                            subcatname' );

$rs = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {

var_dump($row);

}
```

This returns an array like so:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#16 (3) {
    ["subcatname"]=>
    string(29) "Category Name: D.C Ice Makers"
    ["categoryid"]=>
    string(4) "1113"
    ["catname"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#17 (3) {
    ["subcatname"]=>
    string(33) "Category Name: Parry Boiling Tops"
    ["categoryid"]=>
    string(4) "1114"
    ["catname"]=>
    NULL
  }
```

}

However, I'd like to return my results in this format:

```
 array(18) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#258 (3) {
        ["subcatname"]=>
        string(22) "Air Recirculation Unit"
        ["categoryid"]=>
        string(4) "1107"
        ["catname"]=>
        string(18) "Catering Equipment"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#257 (3) {
        ["subcatname"]=>
        string(17) "Beverage Machines"
        ["categoryid"]=>
        string(3) "108"
        ["catname"]=>
        string(18) "Catering Equipment"
      }
    }
```

I've tried experimenting with the "mysql_fetch_object", but I'm struggling to return the results in the format I need. Thanks

Comment: Show us your query.. that's the problem!

Comment: I've included the query, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The query is wrong. Try it like this:

```
SELECT c.catname as subcatname,
       c.categoryid,
       cc.catname
FROM isc_categories c
JOIN isc_categories cc
  ON cc.categoryid = c.catparentid
WHERE c.catparentid = ' . $id . '
  AND c.catvisible = 1
ORDER BY c.catname
```

Use `LEFT JOIN` if you use the same query to get only the top parent categories (when `$id` is 0).

Comment: The query I have works in my SQL Editor, what is the issue with it?